# What is the output of selecting columns with their indices in MySQL?

Tags: sql, sql-injection

I have been going through SQL injection for a while.In that process I have found an article which I can say literally the best article on error based SQL injection.The article is

https://www.hackingarticles.in/beginner-guide-sql-injection-part-1/?unapproved=131901&moderation-hash=e3888f15366f6326c49a0205a79a6d70#comment-131901

In this article he explained everything beautifully.But I didn't understand a small piece of code.That is

```
http://localhost/sqli/Less-1/?id=-1' union select 1,2,3 --+
Or
http://localhost/sqli/Less-1/?id=15' union select 1,2,3 --+
```

for which the output is

[sql injection](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uJ38p.png)

In this the output is

Your login name is 2

and

your password is 3.

I think when we select columns with their indices the output is their column numbers only.Am I wrong?

Answer (score 1):

No, you are correct.

The

```
http://localhost/sqli/Less-1/?id=-1' union select 1,2,3 --+
Or
http://localhost/sqli/Less-1/?id=15' union select 1,2,3 --+
```

query you mention *is selecting columns by indices*, but what it is showing you is what field relates to which column in the database (i.e., `loginname` is `2` and `password` is `3`).